# How to Deploy Php REST API on hosting site

Tags: php, rest, hosting, shared-hosting

I am trying to host slim framework rest api code in hosting site hostgator and I'm not being able to access the api.

It is saying

> The requested file may be moved or not available

I have placed all files under `www/public_html` folder. Please let me know where to place the files and how to access it from browser. The application is simple RESTAPI which will be accessed from local machine as `http://slimapp/hello/world`

Result:

> hello world

Kindly help.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved.
we have to use our website name instead of app name.If we want to use app name we need to modify httpd.vconf file.

> http://.com/public/index.php/hello/world